# Select the first element in a set of CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On a project I'm working on, one of the conventions we want to set up for our users, is that when we open a modal, we automatically focus the first element of the opened modal that can accept an input (either an input or a dropdown.)  The jQuery code for doing that is *easy*:

```
$firstElement.focus();
```

The problem, is getting that first element.

Our application's modals sometimes start with `input`s (e.g. text, checkboxes, dates, etc.), but other times with `select`s (e.g. dropdowns.)  Thus, getting the `$firstElement` is a bit challenging because I need to perform a selection like the following pseudocode:

```
(input, select):first
```

However, the closest I've been able to get based on my knowledge of CSS selectors is:

```
input:first, select:first
```

**Question:** Using CSS selectors, in what way can I select the first element of a set of inputs and selects?  Or, do I need a more complex JavaScript implementation to perform the 'focus first input' thing I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $firstElement = $("input, select, textarea").first();
```

---

**Addendum:**

In case you're using hidden `inputs`, there's a way around that as well:

```
var $firstElement = $("input, select, textarea").filter(':visible:first');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$.fn.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

```
$('input, select').first().focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tabbableElements  = 'a[href], area[href], input:not([type="radio"]):not([disabled]),' +
                                'input[type="radio"]:checked:not([disabled]),' +
                                'select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]),' +
                                'button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, *[tabindex],' +
                                '*[contenteditable]';
var $allTabbableElements = $(context).find(tabbableElements).filter(':visible');
var firstTabbableElement = $allTabbableElements.first()[0];
```

This is part of a code i use for keeping focus within a modal. Hope it helps.