# CSS Selector for the first hit

Tags: jquery, html, web-scraping, css-selectors

CSS Selector are not only used for html page authorization but more and more for web scraping too.

My question is, is it possible to use pure CSS Selector to identify the first (or second) *hit* out of a set of *hits*. For e.g., the google search,

https://www.google.ca/search?q=CSS+Selector+of+the+first+hit

Will yield a number of hits, and each hit can be identified by (is under)

`div.rc`

Say `div.rc` gives me 10 hits, i.e., 10 google search results,
is it possible to use pure CSS Selector to pin-point the first hit, hit#1?

I think none of `:nth-child(n)`, `:first-child`, & `::first-line` is what I'm asking for, and the `.first()` in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628520/" is not a pure CSS Selector, right? Thx.

If all else fails and there is no such CSS Selector, then how about jquery   Selector? Thx.

Comment: *"CSS Selector are not only used for html page authorization"* - That's an odd thing to suggest as a use of CSS selectors. Anyway, I'd have thought `:nth-child()` could work if applied to elements that are siblings. If you're using jQuery, why not just use the `.eq()` method?

Comment: @nnnnnn His problem is that the `div.rc` elements are not siblings, they're each wrapped in several other divs.

Comment: `$("div.rc:first")` should work in jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar - So `"someparentelement:nth-child(1) div.rc"`? (For pure CSS, I mean. With jQuery extensions there's no problem.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12379468/1817690

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div.rc` elements are all wrapped in `div.g` elements, which are siblings. So you can use:

```
div.g:first-child > div.rc
```

In jQuery you can use the `:first` extension.

```
$("#div.rc:first")
```

Comment: To be clear, there is no CSS equivalent to jQuery's first. You have to make assumptions about the structure in order to construct an appropriate selector - which isn't always possible (depending on the sort of pages you're scraping, anyway).